# how to distinguish the target back button in ST2?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I have a little problem here with Sencha Touch 2:

My App has 2 views/lists: news and events. Both have detail views.
On the news list Iam showing an filter and sort button and on the events list Iam want to show only the filter button.

When I click on an item, the nav controller automatically adds an back button.

What I do atm is: 
- when the user clicks an item in the list: hide all buttons
- when the user clicks the back button: show all buttons

And thats the problem... I cannot see if it was the back button on the news detail view or the events detail view.

In my controller I have:

```
"mainnav[id=mainNav]": {
            back: 'showButtons',
        },
```

when I try:

```
"panel[id=newsDetail]": {
            back: 'showButtons',
        },
```

the event gets not triggered.
So how can I know is it was the news or events back button?

Thanks!

Edit: Its not easy to explain... here is some more information:
The "mainNav" is a navigation view and the back button gets added to its toolbar.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MainNav', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
alias: 'widget.mainnav',
config: {
    id: 'mainNav',
    maxWidth: '350px',
    items: [
    {
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        layout : {
            type : 'card'
       },
...
 items: [
       {
        xtype: 'list',
        title: 'News',
        id: 'newsList',
        store: 'newsStore',
        grouped: true,
        onItemDisclosure: true,
...
    {
    xtype: 'list',
    title: 'Events',
    iconCls: 'team',
    id: 'eventList',
    store: 'eventStore',
    onItemDisclosure: true,
...
     tabBar: {
    docked: 'bottom'
}
...
and the navigation bar with its buttons:

navigationBar: {
minWidth: '',
width: '',
id: 'navBar',
layout: {
    align: 'center',
    type: 'hbox'
},
items: [
{
    xtype: 'button',
    id: 'settingsButton',
    align: 'left',
    iconCls: 'settings6',
    iconMask: true
},
    {
    xtype: 'button',
    id: 'filterbutton',
    align: 'right',
    iconCls: 'list',
    iconMask: true
}
]
},
```

What iam trying to do now:

```
"mainnav[id=mainNav]": {
        back: 'showButtons',
    },
```

get triggered when the user hits the back button (doesnt matter if he id in newsDetail or eventsDetail) but I want to know which view the user sees after he taps the back button.

If he sees the news list then I want to show both buttons (filter and seetings) but is he sees the events list I only want to show one button.
I need something like:

```
showButtons: function(component, options) {
  if(Ext.getCmp(backButton).down().getId() == 'newsList'){
    //show 2 buttons
  }else{
    //show one button
  }
}
```

Sorry if the answer is confusing... I dont know how I could explain it better.
Anyway, I would appreciate any help/idea!

Comment: sorry for that... I edited my previous post, hope its better now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a solution:

```
    var activePanel = Ext.getCmp('MainTabPanel').getActiveItem();
    var activeItem = activePanel.getItemId();

    if(activeItem == 'newsList'){
        this.filterNewsStore();
        Ext.getCmp('showSettingsButton').show();
        Ext.getCmp('filterButton').show();
    }

    if(activeItem == 'eventList'){
        this.filterEventsStore();
        Ext.getCmp('showSettingsButton').hide();
        Ext.getCmp('filterButton').show();
    }
```

I call this code when the back button gets fired.

Answer (score 0):

A panel doesn't have a back event. So it will never get fired.

mainnav is a custom xtype you defined right? Else that selector is wrong as well.